# What's the equivalent to force.start() in d3 v5?

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I am converting d3 from v3.5.5 into v5. It has a block of code to force movement in a set of circles.

```
var force = d3.layout.force()
    .nodes(nodes)
    .size([width, height])
    .gravity(0)
    .charge(0)
    .friction(.9)
    .on("tick", tick)
    .start();
```

And it also has a function to pause the action with a `pause/resume` code using `force.resume();`.

I'm trying to move this into the current version of d3. This is my version of the force variable.

```
var force = d3.forceSimulation(nodes)
.velocityDecay(.9)
.force("center", d3.forceCenter(width / 2,height / 2))
.force("charge", d3.forceManyBody().strength())
.on("tick", tick)
.start()
```

I run into two errors. I get a type error that `start()` is not a valid function and I also get an error for the tick function. The code to define the tick is here, but that may be out of scope for this question.

`TypeError: Cannot read property 'alpha' of undefined at Object.tick`

```
function tick(e) {

  var k = 0.03 * e.alpha;

  // Push nodes toward their designated focus.
  nodes.forEach(function(o, i) {
    var curr_act = o.act;

    // Speed of movement change based on user speed.
    if (USER_SPEED == "slow") var damper = .85;
    else var damper = 1;


    o.x += (x(+o.decade) - o.x) * k * damper;

    // If starting at the beginning.
    if (curr_index < 0) {
        o.y += (y('met') - o.y) * k * damper;
        o.color = color('met');
    }

    // Already started.
    else {
        o.y += (y(curr_act) - o.y) * k * damper;
        o.color = color(curr_act);
    }

  });

  circle
      .each(collide(.5))
      .style("fill", function(d) { return d.color; })
      .attr("cx", function(d) { return d.x; })
      .attr("cy", function(d) { return d.y; });
}
```

Is there a new way to `start` the force movement in v5?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the D3.js v5 [changelog for d3.force](https://github.com/d3/d3/blob/master/CHANGES.md#forces-d3-force),

> The force layout’s internal timer now starts automatically on
>   creation, removing force.start.

In d3.js v3.x, you will need to use `d3.layout.force().start()`, but in v5, there is no such need anymore. You can remove `.start()` from your `force` variable which contains that function. This is because `d3.forceSimulation()` starts automatically, as explained over [here](https://github.com/d3/d3-force#forceSimulation).

If for any reason you need to restart the simulation, calling `.restart()` will allow you to [reset](https://github.com/d3/d3-force#simulation_restart) the simulation's internal timer.

You read more about it on that changelog. It has a pretty detailed migration guide to migrate to v4/5.x.

Comment: Is `.force("center", d3.forceCenter(width / 2,height / 2))` the right replacement for `.size()`?

Comment: Hmm.. I think it works too. Does it work when you run your code?

Comment: Well, I'm getting stuck because the `tick` function doesn't work any longer. It gives me the error `TypeError: Cannot read property 'alpha' of undefined at Object.tick`

Comment: You can either use the above, or, you can use this: https://github.com/d3/d3-force/blob/master/README.md#x_x . So, it goes, something like `.force('x', d3.forceX(width / 2)`

Comment: Ok, but the `tick()` function has not been working all these while, right?

Comment: Yeah, it worked in the old version but not the new one. I added a `console.log(e)` and before, it printed something like this. https://i.imgur.com/W1nWIdR.png but in the new version it prints `undefined`

Comment: Hmm.. I am not sure how to solve the `tick()` problem. Do you want to open a new question for that instead? So that others may see it. People may not know that is part of your question, since it is not reflected on your title..!

Comment: I opened a part of it here since I think something might be wrong with `quadtree`. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55941750/is-the-behavior-different-for-quadtree-visit-in-d3-v5 I'll do one specific to this. Thanks for your help and making this community welcoming!

Comment: Here's the post with this specific piece: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55941955/converting-tick-from-d3-v3-to-v5