# Converting `tick()` from d3 v3 to v5

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I have a `force` function that works in d3 V3 and I'd like to convert it to V5. I'll show the solution that works right now and then go into what's broken.

**This works in v3**

```
var force = d3.layout.force()
    .nodes(nodes)
    .size([width, height])
    .gravity(0)
    .charge(0)
    .friction(.9)
    .on("tick", tick)
    .start();

function tick(e) {

  var k = 0.03 * e.alpha;

  // Push nodes toward their designated focus.
  nodes.forEach(function(o, i) {
    var curr_act = o.act;

    var damper = .85;

    o.x += (x(+o.decade) - o.x) * k * damper;
    o.y += (y('met') - o.y) * k * damper;
    o.color = color('met');

 });

  circle
      .each(collide(.5))
      .style("fill", function(d) { return d.color; })
      .attr("cx", function(d) { return d.x; })
      .attr("cy", function(d) { return d.y; });
}

// Resolve collisions between nodes.
function collide(alpha) {

  var quadtree = d3.geom.quadtree(nodes);

  return function(d) {
    var r = d.radius + maxRadius + padding,
        nx1 = d.x - r,
        nx2 = d.x + r,
        ny1 = d.y - r,
        ny2 = d.y + r;
    quadtree.visit(function(quad, x1, y1, x2, y2) {

      if (quad.point && (quad.point !== d)) {
        var x = d.x - quad.point.x,
            y = d.y - quad.point.y,
            l = Math.sqrt(x * x + y * y),
            r = d.radius + quad.point.radius + (d.act !== quad.point.act) * padding;
        if (l < r) {
          l = (l - r) / l * alpha;
          d.x -= x *= l;
          d.y -= y *= l;
          quad.point.x += x;
          quad.point.y += y;
        }
      }
      return x1 > nx2 || x2 < nx1 || y1 > ny2 || y2 < ny1;
    });
  };
}
```

where the object `circles` is defined as.

```
var circle = svg.selectAll("circle")
    .data(nodes)
    .enter().append("circle")
```

And [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9ZFIo.png) is an example of a node.

**This is my attempt to convert it to v5**

```
var force = d3.forceSimulation(nodes)
.velocityDecay(.9)
.force("center", d3.forceCenter(width / 2,height / 2))
.force("charge", d3.forceManyBody().strength())
.on("tick", tick)
```

I kept everything else the same except that I replaced `d3.geom.quadtree(nodes)` with `d3.quadtree(nodes)`.

I am having trouble with the `tick` function. In the old version, the `e` argument prints something like this.

[image]

In the new version, it prints undefined and the function breaks with `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'alpha' of undefined`.

Does `tick()` have a new format or a new way of passing arguments in v5?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are trying to access simulation properties during the simulation's ticks, you no longer use an event passed as a parameter to the tick function. Instead you can access the simulation directly with `this`.

From the docs:

> When a specified event is dispatched, each listener will be invoked with the this context as the simulation. ([docs](https://github.com/d3/d3-force#simulation_on)).

Which means that you can access alpha, for example, with `this.alpha()` (or `simulation.alpha()`), within the tick function in v4/v5:

```js
d3.forceSimulation()
  .velocityDecay(.9)
  .force("charge", d3.forceManyBody().strength())
  .on("tick", tick)  
  .nodes([{},{}]);
  
function tick() {
  console.log(this.alpha());
}
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper {
  min-height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/5.7.0/d3.min.js"></script>
```